# Is the closed half real line a meet-semilattice?

Tags: soft-question, definition, real-numbers, lattice-orders

Extremely simple question

**Is $\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0} = [0, \infty)$ a meet-semilattice?**

Consider any two numbers $x,y \in \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$, $x \land y = \inf\{x,y\} = x$ if $x \leq y$ and $y$ if $y < x$

Just to make sure before I use a new concept, because nothing is written about this.

Comment: Yes, it is, but you mean $x\land y$, not $x\lor y$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is: the meet of two non-negative real numbers is simply the minimum of the two numbers. $\Bbb R$ is also a meet semilattice. Indeed, any linear order is a lattice: the meet of two elements is their minimum, and the join is their maximum.

Comment: I thought $\mathbb{R}$ would not be a meet or joint semilattice because $\pm \infty$. What happens if we meet $(-\infty, a) \land (-\infty, b)$, or joint $(a, \infty) \vee (b, \infty)$

Comment: @BeachedWhale: All that’s required is that every pair of real numbers have a meet or join, and they do. This implies (by a straightforward induction argument) that every non-empty finite set of real numbers has a meet or join. It’s not required that *infinite* sets have a meet or join.

Comment: Then $\mathbb{R}$ would be a lattice, and not a complete lattice correct? Wow I wonder why wikipedia doesn't discuss $\Bbb R$ in the examples section at all. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_(order)

Comment: @BeachedWhale: Yes, that’s correct. ($\Bbb R$ is conditionally complete, however.) If I had to guess, whoever wrote that article felt that the example of the positive integers was a sufficient illustration of linearly ordered lattices.

Comment: @BeachedWhale. What do you mean with $(-\infty,a) \wedge (-\infty,b)$? These are subsets of $\mathbb{R}$, rather than elements. That still makes sense, but then we're talking about some sublattice (or subsemilattice) of the powerset of $\mathbb{R}$, which, as any other powerset, is a Boolean Algebra (thus, a lattice).